# Secure Way to Store Credentials for an API python module

Tags: python, api, passwords

I am using a python `API` module called [SpaceTrackTools](https://pypi.org/project/spacetracktool/). However, it requires the script to have the password and username stored as variables in the script. I was wondering if there is a safer way of saving the details?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) to store your username and password outside your script. A command-line interface allows you to get, set, or delete a stored password. You can store your username as if it were a password to keep it secure.

```
$ keyring --help
Usage: keyring [get|set|del] SERVICE USERNAME

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p KEYRING_PATH, --keyring-path=KEYRING_PATH
                        Path to the keyring backend
  -b KEYRING_BACKEND, --keyring-backend=KEYRING_BACKEND
                        Name of the keyring backend
  --list-backends       List keyring backends and exit
  --disable             Disable keyring and exit
```

Set the username and password for the service from the command line.

```
$ keyring set spacetracktools username
Password for 'username' in 'spacetracktools': 
$ keyring set spacetracktools password
Password for 'password' in 'spacetracktools':
```

```
import keyring

# get username and password from keyring
username = keyring.get_password("spacetracktools", "username")
password = keyring.get_password("spacetracktools", "password")

print("My username is:", username)
print("My password is:", password)
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

This way you keep your private details in a separate file named `.env`.

Then you read the private details in your script at run time.

For Example:

File .env values:

```
USERNAME=MyUserName
PASSWORD=Spec!alP@ssw0rd*19?
```

Script Usage:

```
import os  # also need os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # blank if .env file in same directory as script
# load_dotenv('<path to file>.env') to point to another location
USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME')
PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')

# your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the .env approach please make sure you have a .gitignore file that is set so that git will not include the .env file in the repo. You can find a .gitignore file for python at the Github gitignore repo [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)